# php7.0-fpm.service is masked

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, ubuntu-16.04

I can't seem to get php to start anymore and it's telling me it's masked which from googling appears to be a super disable? Can anyone tell me how to unmask it?

What happened was I did some updates sudo apt-get update and then I shutdown my server and migrated it to a bigger EC2 instance on AWS. When I fired it back up I was getting nginx 502 bad gateway errors. I checked nginx was working and then php which is not working so far as I can tell.

Edit: So I found sudo systemctl unmask php7.0-fpm and that did the trick for php. However I am still getting 502 errors. Is there a way to list all my services and see if anything else isn't running that should be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was not that php7.0-fpm wasn't running. It was that ubuntu had installed php7.1-fpm and my nginx config still was pointing to php7.0-fpm.sock I changed the nginx.conf to php7.1-fpm.sock and restart then it worked.

Comment: I essentially made the same change to the Web site's sites-available config file on Apache 2.4.29 on Ubuntu, after an in-place upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS upgraded the package version to php7.2-fpm.